# Why is this one page not loading its css?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, pug

I can't figure out why this one page isn't loading properly. All the other pages in my website are fine. I've tried adding a link to the css in all the files, but that didn't fix it. I've also tried combining the filter file with the main file, but that didn't work either. Knowing me I'm just missing something basic. The styles.css file isn't being accessed properly and the error code is 404.
(This is my first website)

Router:

```
router.get('/flags/:filter', viewController.getFilteredFlagOverview);
```

Export:

```
exports.getFilteredFlagOverview = async (req, res) => {
  const params = req.params.filter;
  const flags = await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/flags?${params}`
  });
  var filteredObj = flags.data.data.doc;

  res.status(200).render('flagOverview', {
    title: 'Flags',
    products: filteredObj
  });
};
```

Base pug:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    mets(name='viewpoint' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    title Color Guard | #{title}
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css')
    link(rel='shortcut icon' type='image/png' href='img/favicon.png')
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,700')
```

Product pug:

```
extends base

block content
  head
    include productFilters/_flagFilter
  style.
    .tab1 {
      tab-size: 2;
      }
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a9879bc1c3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  main.main
  // don't think past this is important
```

Filter file - where I believe the issue is:

```
filter.filter
  #mySidenav.sidenav
    a.closebtn(href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='closeNav()') &times;
//

//
  br
    a.filterBtn(onclick='applyFilter()') Apply Filter
    br

  button.btn.btn--purple.btn--small(onclick='openNav()') Filter
  .dropdown
    button.btn.btn--purple.btn--small Sell Your Flags
      .dropdown-content
        a(href='/createFlagSilk') Flag Silk
        a(href='/createFlagPole') Flag Pole
        a(href='/createFlagStopper') Flag Stopper
        a(href='/createFlagBolt') Flag Bolt

  script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js')
  script(src='/js/index.js')
  script(type='text/javascript')
  script.
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "275px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }

    async function applyFilter() {
      var params = '';
      var temp = document.getElementById('flag_category');
      var category = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
      temp = document.getElementById('flag_color');
      var color = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
      temp = document.getElementById('flag_theme');
      var theme = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
      temp = document.getElementById('flag_flagType');
      var flagType = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
      temp = document.getElementById('flag_fabricType');
      var fabricType = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;

      if (color) params = params + `color=${color}`
      if (category && color) params = params + `&category=${category}`
      if (category && !color) params = params + `category=${category}`
      if (theme && (color || category)) params = params + `&theme=${theme}`
      if (theme && !color && !category) params = params + `theme=${theme}`
      if (flagType && (color || category || theme)) params = params + `&flagType=${flagType}`
      if (flagType && !color && !category && !theme) params = params + `flagType=${flagType}`
      if (fabricType && (color || category || theme || flagType)) params = params + `&fabricType=${fabricType}`
      if (fabricType && !color && !category && !theme && !flagType) params = params + `fabricType=${fabricType}`

      window.location.replace(`/flags/${params}`);
    };
```

And I tried this to see if it would work, and the first "render product" works, but the second does not.

```
exports.getOverview = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).render('product', {
    title: 'Product Selection'
  });
};

exports.getFilteredFlagOverview = async (req, res) => {
  /*
  const params = req.params.filter;
  const flags = await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/flags?${params}`
  });
  var filteredObj = flags.data.data.doc;
  */
  res.status(200).render('product', {
    title: 'Flags'
  });
};
```

Comment: are you sure it is not a browser caching issue? Tried clearing browser cache?

Comment: @NikosM. If only it was that simple. Didn't fix it. Thanks for the guess.

Comment: what is your browser saying about the page css? (open browser cosnole and look under styles tab or network tab depending on browser). is the linked css loaded successfully?

Comment: can you provide the rendered page source code (or at least the part where the css is linked, probably inside <head>)? This would help alot

Comment: @NikosM. It says "an error occurred trying to load the resource".

Comment: The this seems to be the problem, either a wrong link is provided or if the css is generated dynamicaly an error occurs try to find out more about why it failed to load (browser can give a lot of information in styles or netwrok tab, for example what is the response code is it 4xx or 5xx?) Add this info in your post and if needed add any relevant code

Comment: @NikosM. I added some code I tried and the error code (404).

Comment: 404 code means the resource is NOT FOUND. So it seems the url of the css is wrong or not setup properly. Search along this direction. Cant say more if I dont know the whole stup of the project and how it is served

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change

```
link(rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css')
```

with

```
link(rel='stylesheet' href='http://127.0.0.1:3000/css/style.css')
```

in the base pug.